# Comparing data across executors in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

We have a spark application, in which data is shared across different executors. But we also need to compare data between executors, where some data is present in executor-1, and some data is present in executor-2. We wanted to know how can we achieve in spark?

For example: have a file with following details:

```
Name, Date1, Date2
A, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-23
A, 2019-02-12, 2019-03-21
A, 2019-04-01, 2019-05-31
A, 2019-06-02, 2019-12-30
B, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-21
B, 2019-02-10, 2019-03-21
B, 2019-04-01, 2019-12-31
```

I need to find total gaps between these elements by checking date2 of first row, against date1 of second row, and so on.. i.e.

> For example: for Name A: (2019-02-12 - 2019-01-23) + (2019-04-01 - 2019-03-21) + (2019-06-02 -2019-05-31) + (2019-12-31 - 2019-12-30) .. Year is ending on 2019-12-31, so there is gap of 1 day
> and also number of gaps (if difference between above formula per date > 0)
> will be 4.
>
> For Name B: (2019-02-10 - 2019-01-21) + (2019-04-01 -
> 2019-03-21), and number of gaps would be 2.

One approach is to use *collectAsList()*, which retrieves all data to driver, but is there a different efficient way to compare them directly across executors, if yes how can we do that?

Comment: The question is too vague, please provide a better example. The whole idea is to process per partition, but I grant you in some cases there are some issues to consider, so an example would be helpful. It's a good question none-the-less.

Comment: @thebluephantom, I have updated the question, and provided an example.

Comment: What about Name?

Comment: @thebluephantom,  Total gaps will be checked per name entry. If there multiple names in file, differences will be provided per name.

Comment: You should update the question to show the case of 2 differeng names please.

Comment: I suspect your executor aspect is incorrect.

Comment: @thebluephantom, I have updated the query with names

Comment: Provided you write correctly the query all data will be shuffled to same executor for processing.

Comment: so 2 adjacent dates mean no gap

Comment: Yes, 2 adjacent dates means no gap. How can we achieve that in executors

Comment: Just write an sql query with lag windowing, qualifying, check the adjacent rows with major key qualification being Name. You need not worry about Executors, Spark will hash for you automatically.

Comment: Getting the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write an SQL query with lag windowing, qualifying, check the adjacent rows for date ad date minus 1, with major key qualification being Name. Sort as well within Name.

You need not worry about Executors, Spark will hash for you automatically based on Name to a Partition serviced by an Executor.